# android contacts intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

i'm looking for an intent filter for when you are at the contact list and you long press a contact so a menu comes up

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As Falmarri said, there isn't going to be an intent for something that specific.

Comment: i'd like to be able to long press on the contact and in the menu that comes up, i'd like to be able to click and option that will automatically send a pre-defined message to that contact

Answer (score 0):

There's almost assuredly not an intent sent for that action.

Comment: i'd like to be able to long press on the contact and in the menu that comes up, i'd like to be able to click and option that will automatically send a pre-defined message to that contact

Comment: Oh. Well that won't be possible. If you mean when you click on their picture, that little window pops up with the different things you can do. There's probably a chooser for that, I'm not sure what that is though.

Answer (score 0):

this intent filter will capture your click (not long click) when you're at the "All" list in your contacts app:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

put that in your app's manifest, install it, and android will ask you what to use

**NOTE: there is no intent generated when you long-click on a contact in the contact list of stock contacts app**